# create concatenate AND function from sql statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have mysql database with fulltext index UTF-8 encoding with MyISAM engine.
From database I CAN perform this sql:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE 
CONCAT(column1, column2, column3) LIKE '%free%' AND
CONCAT(column1, column2, column3) LIKE '%floor%'
```

*free* and *floor* are examples word. In this situation **database returns me rows with *both* words only**. If a row have 'free' word in the 1st column and 'floor' in the 3rd column - database returns me values but if these both words are not included in the same row database don't match anything.

But... my problem is to transform this statement in php code..

I have this code:

```
static function filter ( $request, $columns, &$bindings )
{
    $globalSearch = array();
    $columnSearch = array();
    $dtColumns = self::pluck( $columns, 'dt' );

    if ( isset($request['search']) && $request['search']['value'] != '' ) {
        $str = $request['search']['value'];

        for ( $i=0, $ien=count($request['columns']) ; $i<$ien ; $i++ ) {
            $requestColumn = $request['columns'][$i];
            $columnIdx = array_search( $requestColumn['data'], $dtColumns );
            $column = $columns[ $columnIdx ];

            if ( $requestColumn['searchable'] == 'true' ) {
                $binding = self::bind( $bindings, '%'.$str.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR );
                //$globalSearch[] = "match(".$column['db'].") against (".$binding.")";
                $globalSearch[] = "`".$column['db']."` LIKE ".$binding;
            }
        }
    }
```

but I don't know how change this code to make it like concatenating function and I don't know how must be included "$str" as space separated text.

Here is example that is NOT concatenate words but it is similar to what I try: [LIVE DEMO](http://datatables.altervista.org/yadcf1/examples/server_side/simple.html)

For doubt's sake, I also insert [complete code](http://pastebin.com/fN0rsPkT) of which the code snippet above is son

Comment: can you explain bit more and make sure what output you want...

Comment: go to [Live Demo](http://datatables.altervista.org/yadcf1/examples/server_side/simple.html). If you type on Global Search `giraffa dreams` you have 31 entries (because my php code above works like an OR operator -> giraffa OR dreams) BUT this I don't want because I want only 2 entries rows (giraffa AND dreams).

Comment: no matter if words ​​are on the same column or different columns . Just that the function I works as an AND function so filtering is more accurate